# How to save a video file with a specific name in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Firstly I have this code which saves my video file in the documents directory:

```
filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%f.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Secondly I have a `UIAlertView` that allows the user to enter the name they want for the video they are saving:

```
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"GIVE YOURE VIDEO A NAME" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        [alert show];
```

And I have this to display what is entered:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        if (alertView.alertViewStyle == UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput){
            NSLog(@"Entered: %@",[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]);

        }


         }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"user pressed Button Indexed 1");
        // Any action can be performed here
    }
}
```

Know that I want to do is to save the video file with a name specified by text which was entered in to the `UIAlertView`. To do this I need to change this line: `filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%f.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];` which saves the file as the current date and time to the entered text. However, I do not know how I would go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to replace the date with the text entered ?

You only need to pass in the string, which you are already doing with the homeDirectory, like so

```
filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]];
```